# Value counts of 2 columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table in the below format. I would like to do the value counts of both the columns (year and operation) and get their percentage.

For example, in year `2014`, value `yes` appears `2` out of `3` times, hence `2/3 = 0.66`. I tried with `value_counts` but it did not yield the below results.
Any leads would be appreciated.

```
df[['year', 'operation']].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)

year operation
2014    yes
2014    yes
2014    no
2015    
2015    yes
2015    yes

Result:

2014   yes     0.66
2014   no      0.33
2015           0.33
2015   yes     0.66
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and set `normalize=True` to get the values as a percentage:

```
out = df.groupby('year')['operation'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

`out`:

```
year  operation
2014  yes          0.666667
      no           0.333333
2015  yes          0.666667
                   0.333333
Name: operation, dtype: float64
```

---

Can also set `sort=False` to not sort with highest value per level 0:

```
out = df.groupby('year')['operation'].value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False)
```

`out`:

```
year  operation
2014  no           0.333333
      yes          0.666667
2015               0.333333
      yes          0.666667
Name: operation, dtype: float64
```

---

[`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) can be used with `name=` set to create a DataFrame instead of a Series and give a name to the unnamed values column:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby('year')['operation'].value_counts(normalize=True)
        .reset_index(name='freq')
)
```

```
   year operation      freq
0  2014       yes  0.666667
1  2014        no  0.333333
2  2015       yes  0.666667
3  2015            0.333333
```

---

DataFrame Used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015],
                   'operation': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', '', 'yes', 'yes']})
```

Comment: Just as a warning: Groupby silently drops nans and Nones, so if the empty field in operations would be a missing value it would be gone from the list.

Comment: Correct, the default argument for _both_ [Series.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) and [Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) have `dropna=True` as the default. So, together ([SeriesGroupby.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html)) they can drop a lot of NaN-like values. Though to be clear this is standard behaviour for both operations so this is not a special case.